# running Winform Application

Tags: winforms

[detailed message box text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDo3d.png)i made a winform application on my pc and it runs fine. but when I tried to run it on another PC by copying the exe file and other dll files there  , the application failed to run and all of a sudden it shows a dialog box to close the aplication.
please refer to screenshot of error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjuhV.png)

Comment: what's the detailed information of the message box?

Comment: Were you trying to run it on same OS version? Same .net runtime library installed?

Comment: yes , the OS version is same and .net runtime library is also same...

Comment: I have added the detailed message box screenshot in the question.please refer the same

Comment: A `FileNotFoundException` indicates that somewhere in your code you're is trying to access a file, which seems to be not existing on the other computer. If you have any code that tries to open / read files then please add it to your post. Otherwise try to add some error handling to get further exception details (exception message, stack trace, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Like bassfader said: One possible explanation is that your application is handling files during startup. In that case: integrate more extensive exception handling for those parts. Potentially with logging, to locate the problem

In my experience this however is more often a case of missing some kind of dependency.

- Double check .NET runtimes. Lookup the target .net version in Visual Studio and run the installer on the target machine.
- Investigate if your app uses any assemblies that are not part of the .NET framework. Sometimes these are not copied to the bin directory if they are in the GAC (ensure the flag "Copy Local" is set to "Always" in Visual Studio)
- Ensure you have copied the whole bin folder
- Check compiler output to see if you've got Platform mismatches. IIRC this can sometimes work fine on a dev machine but cause problems when Visual Studio is missing or you get to a different OS.